# How to get a list of related items and apply a template filter in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom filter that joins an array of items by a specified character. For example it will turn:

In view:

```
test_array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

In template:

```
{{ test_array |joinby:","  }}
```

Output:

`one, two, three, four`

I need to apply this same filter to a queryset of related items from a model. I have tried this so far:

```
{{ user.related_model.all.name|joinby:","  }}
```

However it just returns nothing. What is the best way to get this type of query to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to keep the template clean, and create a filter, or handle this in your view.

In the view:

```
def my_view(request):
    #blah
    user_followers = request.user.related_model.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

and in the template

```
{{ user_followers | joinby: "," }}
```

Or

Register a filter

```
@register.filter(name='related_names')
def get_related_names(user):
    user_followers = user.related_model.values_list('name', flat=True)
    return ", ".join(user_followers)
```

and in the template:

```
{% related_names %}
```